# Filtering to physical NICs in WMIC on XP

Tags: windows-xp, wmic

If I enter this in Windows 7 I can filter the NICs to ones that have a physical adapter

```
WMIC NIC WHERE PhysicalAdapter="TRUE" GET /VALUE
```

But in XP all I get is "Invalid Query" because it doesn't have a `PhysicalAdapter` property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, would be nice to have a confirmation or improvement:

```
WMIC NIC WHERE MACAddress^>="1" GET /VALUE
```

Gets all NICs with macaddress but ignores ones that start with a zero.